# Vertical lines going across my PC monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hardware-failure

How do I get rid of 15 vertical lines going across my PC monitor?

It is a HP Pavilion desktop running Windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: Try an other monitor to determine if the problem in in your PC (or your PCs graphical card) or in the display.

Comment: If you don't have a monitor, download a linux live session cd and boot from that. That way you will know if the problem is hardware or software related.

Answer (score 1):

HP Pavilions were notorious for a design defect that led to a successful class action suit in USA [(eg)](http://www.pavilioninverterclassaction.com/CaseInfo.aspx?pas=hpr), but pitiful recompense there (other than for the lawyers) and nothing at all elsewhere. Basically, the copper cooling strip was underdesigned and, I hear, in some cases there was no thermal jelly. (Yes, it is still a sore point as I don't want a doorstop for GBP5k.)

The symptoms you mention are too familiar.

However, there is some good news as IF this is your problem baking the board [(eg)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsmlALfEgPg) does sometimes work. Afterwards you should be OK because a reputable repair shop will upgrade the copper strip and apply suitable jelly.

Updating the BIOS may help (keeps fan running - whatever the specific cause, it is is likely to be heat related).